# average sequence of lag variables R

Tags: r, dataframe, lag, lead

Is there a better way to compute the average of the 3 previous time periods (or N time periods) to compute a function (mean, sum, etc.) using lead or lag?

```
data_final <- data_final %>%
    group_by(cars) %>%
    mutate(last3_average = (lag(speed, 1) + lag(speed, 2) + lag(speed, 3))/3)
```

I used the zoo package as suggested below:

```
data_final <- data_final %>%
    group_by(cars) %>%
    mutate(last3_average = lag(rollmean(speed, 3, na.pad = T, align = "right"), 1))
```

Comment: yes, is there a better way to automate this if you had say 100 time periods?

Comment: It is possible my data was setup different but incorporating rollmean and lag did the trick: `mutate(last3_avg = lag(rollmean(speed, 3, na.pad = T, align = "right"), 1))`